# EventBrite API - How Do I Get Only Live Events for my User?

Tags: eventbrite

I'm using PHP and CURL to try and get all my account's events from EventBrite's web service.

I'm running this script (edited down slightly):

```
        $curl = curl_init();
        $hdr = array();
        $hdr[] = 'Authorization: Bearer <MY TOKEN>';
        $hdr[] = 'Content-type: application/json';



        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER, $hdr);

        curl_setopt(
        $curl, 
        CURLOPT_URL, 
        'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?status=live'
        );
        curl_setopt($curl, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
        $events = curl_exec($curl);
        print_r($results);
```

But the status=live parameter is not taking effect and all events including drafts are being returned.

Has anyone successfully achieved a list of live events using EventBrite's API and if so, can you advise me how you managed and where I went wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For the benefit of anyone else with a similar problem, the issue was the "Content-Type" header. Remove this, and all is well with the world.

Answer (score 0):

I'm unsure if I just helped you via email, but after troubleshooting I've deducted that this will only return 'live' events if you also pass in 'started' as a status parameter.

Ex.) `'https://www.eventbriteapi.com/v3/users/me/owned_events/?status=live,started'`

I hope this helps!

Comment: Hi, yes, I think we've been corresponding. I've replied by e-mail. Just thought I'd see if anyone else out there on the internet had solved this in the meantime. Will post the solution here when it's sorted.